# Is studying similar with learning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, word-difference

What is the difference between "studying" and "learning"?

What will a student do?

What will a learner do?

Comment: You can be a *student* but you don't necessarily *learn*. (Probably because you could fail at exams.) You can be a *learner* without being a *student*. (Because you can *learn* how things are done by just watching others doing them.)

Comment: I'd like to point out that exams are not an exhaustive measure of learning.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is subtle. Studying is engaging in a mental process for the purpose of the acquisition of knowledge (such as reading a textbook). Learning is the actual acquisition of knowledge through some process such as studying, instruction, or experience. So, the desired outcome of studying something is learning (about) that thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an impression that learning means knowledge, experience or a moral of a story flowing into your mind, as in

> [Here’s what we learned from the South Carolina primary and Nevada caucuses](http://www.pbs.org/newshour/bb/heres-what-we-learned-from-the-south-carolina-primary-and-nevada-caucuses/)
>
> [How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove)

and studying means an act of attending a school or an act of working on an educational material.

"Study" also means "doing research," as in

> [More Higgs particles can be found by studying superfluid helium](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/01/160108084427.htm)

It's not guaranteed that we gain any knowledge about Higgs particles by "studying" superfluid helium.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between "studying" and "learning"?

When you say you are "learning" something, that suggests it's more an ongoing process...it doesn't happen in an instant.

When you say *"I am studying English"* you might be talking about something you are doing right now.  You could just have a book open and be in the act of "studying" it.  But you could also mean it is an ongoing process...since you haven't really said anything about when your studying will will end.

So in the case of these two statements, the meaning *might* be the same, depending on context:

- I am studying English.
- I am learning English.

However with these two:

- I am studying English tonight.
- I am learning English tonight.

Really only the first would make sense *(unless you are living in [The Matrix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8ZdGmgj0PQ) and can instantly download English to your brain.)*  Studying can start and stop.  But hopefully, no one ever promises to stop learning things *ever* again...